# Mapping index values from one dataframe to another in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, mapping

I have a dataframe `df_in` like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dic_in = {'A':['A1','A1','A1','L3','A3','A3','B1','B1','B1','B2','A2'],
       'B':['xxx','ttt','qqq','nnn','lll','nnn','eee','xxx','qqq','bbb','sss'],
       'C':['fas','efe','pfo','scs','grj','rpo','cbb','asf','asc','wq3','mls']}
df_in = pd.DataFrame(dic_in)
```

I also have a another dataframe which is called `df_map`:

```
dic_map = {'X':['A1' ,'A1' ,'A1' ,'A2' ,'A3' ,'B1' ,'B1' ,'B1' ,'B1' ,'B2' ,'B3' ,'B3' ,'L1', 'L3' ,'L3'],
           'Y':['qqq','ttt','xxx','sss','lll','eee','qqq','xxx','zzz','bbb','mmm','ooo','kkk','nnn','ttt']}
df_map = pd.DataFrame(dic_map)
```

My goal is to study every single `row[['A','B']]` of `df_in`; if the couple of items is identified within `df_map`, then I extract the value of the corresponding index and I set it to another column in the first dataframe.

Ex:  the couple `A1 - xxx` is found in map in the `0`; therefore I will place a `0` next to the couple `A1 - xxx`. 
If a couple is not found then I will place `NaN`.

The result should look like this:

```
    Idx   A    B    C
0     2  A1  xxx  fas
1     1  A1  ttt  efe
2     0  A1  qqq  pfo
3    13  L3  nnn  scs
4     4  A3  lll  grj
5   NaN  A3  nnn  rpo
6     5  B1  eee  cbb
7     7  B1  xxx  asf
8     6  B1  qqq  asc
9     9  B2  bbb  wq3
10    3  A2  sss  mls
```

Can you suggest me a smart and efficient way to reach my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), last remove columns by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
print (pd.merge(df_in, 
                df_map.reset_index(), 
                left_on=['A','B'], 
                right_on=['X','Y'], 
                how='left').drop(['X','Y'], axis=1))

     A    B    C  index
0   A1  xxx  fas    2.0
1   A1  ttt  efe    1.0
2   A1  qqq  pfo    0.0
3   L3  nnn  scs   13.0
4   A3  lll  grj    4.0
5   A3  nnn  rpo    NaN
6   B1  eee  cbb    5.0
7   B1  xxx  asf    7.0
8   B1  qqq  asc    6.0
9   B2  bbb  wq3    9.0
10  A2  sss  mls    3.0
```

Another solution, thank you [Julien Marrec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978186/mapping-index-values-from-one-dataframe-to-another-in-pandas#comment69165978_40978236):

```
df_in.merge(df_map.reset_index()
                  .set_index(['X','Y']), 
            left_on=['A','B'], 
            right_index=True, 
            how='left')
```

---

Last if want change order of columns:

```
df = pd.merge(df_in, 
              df_map.reset_index(), 
              left_on=['A','B'], 
              right_on=['X','Y'], 
              how='left').drop(['X','Y'], axis=1)
cols = df.columns[-1:].tolist() + df.columns[:-1].tolist()
print (cols)
['index', 'A', 'B', 'C']

df = df[cols]
print (df)
    index   A    B    C
0     2.0  A1  xxx  fas
1     1.0  A1  ttt  efe
2     0.0  A1  qqq  pfo
3    13.0  L3  nnn  scs
4     4.0  A3  lll  grj
5     NaN  A3  nnn  rpo
6     5.0  B1  eee  cbb
7     7.0  B1  xxx  asf
8     6.0  B1  qqq  asc
9     9.0  B2  bbb  wq3
10    3.0  A2  sss  mls
```

Comment: You beat me to it, I came up with `df_in.merge(df_map.reset_index().set_index(['X','Y']), left_on=['A','B'], right_index=True, how='left')`

Comment: What if  I want to shift the index by 1 during the operation in such a way that the mapped indexes values are all +1?

Comment: By shift the index, do you mean after the merge, `df['index'] += 1`?

Comment: Or before merge? like `shifted = df_map.reset_index()`
`shifted['index'] = shifted['index'].shift()` and then `df = pd.merge(df_in, 
              shifted, 
              left_on=['A','B'], 
              right_on=['X','Y'], 
              how='left').drop(['X','Y'], axis=1)` ?

Comment: well I was thinking to do it during the merge possibly... if it is not possible then i believe doing it before is better

Comment: I think in `merge not`, but before or after it is possible. before like `shifted = df_map.reset_index()` `shifted['index'] += 1` and after same way.